# Как пунктуационно оформить вопрос в предложении, если он - цитата?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, вопрос

Подскажите, нужно ли оформлять вопрос-цитату, как в прямой речи, или это всего лишь сложносочиненное предложение и кавычки здесь не нужны?

Пример:

> Если вы задаетесь вопросом «Где лучшие тусовки?»

Answer (score 1):

Если ваш вопрос является прямой речью, цитатой, то оформлять его нужно как прямую речь. Из "Правил русской орфографии и пунктуации"<sup>1</sup>:

> §134. (...) Если прямая речь стоит после слов автора, то эти слова заканчиваются двоеточием; знаки препинания, стоящие после прямой речи, сохраняются.

Соответственно:

*Если вы задаетесь вопросом: «Где лучшие тусовки?»*

Если же это не цитата, то тогда кавычки можно не ставить; но и вопросительный знак тут не уместен, ведь предложение не является вопросительным; и заглавная буква не нужна, ведь это часть того же предложения:

*Если вы задаетесь вопросом, где лучшие тусовки*

Окончание предложения я специально не делаю, потому что вы не указываете в каком контексте вы используете фразу. Но оно там должно быть. Если это начало предложения, то его надо продолжить. Если это элемент списка, то ставится либо точка с запятой, либо точка (если последний элемент).

---

1. Валгина Н. С., Еськова Н. А., Иванова О. Е., Кузьмина С. М., Лопатин В. В., Чельцова Л. К. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под редакцией В. В. Лопатина. — 2-е изд., испр. и доп. — М.: Эксмо, 2007.

Answer (score 0):

Ваше предложение неполное, поэтому полностью пунктуацию восстановить нельзя.

Но главное: если это именно цитата, то вопросительный знак там нужен тогда и только тогда, когда он есть в первоисточнике. Если же это ваше предложение, то ваше право оформить и как прямую речь и как СПП, последнее, судя по всему, используется чаще.

Если же говорить о пунктуационном оформлении (полагаю, что вопрос предполагал именно это), то тут тоже нет ничего сложного. В отношении кавычек - все по обычным правилам.

Есть одна оговорка: dопросительный знак не повторяется после кавычек, если он имеется перед закрывающейся кавычкой.

***Как бы вы ответили на вопрос "Где лучшие тусовки?"***

Это оговаривается в примечании к § 200 правил-56.

> Примечание 1. Если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит знак
> вопросительный, или восклицательный, или многоточие, то те же самые
> знаки не повторяются после кавычек; неодинаковые же знаки, если они
> требуются в силу характера соответствующих частей текста, могут
> ставиться перед закрывающими кавычками и после них, например:
>
> ```
> Читали ли вы роман Чернышевского «Что делать?»
> ```

Впрочем, это правило иногда трактуют по-иному, поэтому таких вариантов лучше просто избегать.